# Reaching memory limit in R

Tags: r, date, memory, memory-leaks

I am having a strange issue in R.

I have a large data.table dataTs1 :

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  419172 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ TimeStamp: chr  "01MAR13:07:15:00" "01MAR13:07:16:00" "01MAR13:07:18:00" ...
 $ col1     : chr  "ALL1" "ALL1" "ALL1" "ALL1" ...
 $ col2     : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ col3     : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ col4     : int  621 810 4 4 8 1 3 1 1 1 ...
```

I loaded this table using `fread` function.

The memory allocation seems ok.

```
> memory.size(max=TRUE)
[1] 82.94
```

I tried to modify the class of the first line to POSIX so I wrote :

> dataTs1$TimeStamp <- strptime(dataTs1$TimeStamp,"%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")

And with this line I get reach my memory limit of 16G... but when I write :

```
test <- 1:length(dataTs1$TimeStamp)
dataTs1$TimeStamp <- test
```

it works perfectly without any memory overload.

I am pretty new with R and I would be grateful If you could help me figuring out what I'm doing wrong here.

Thx

---

EDIT :

Actually I get a strange warning sometimes when I don't get a memory overload :

```
>dataTs1[,TimeStamp:=strptime(TimeStamp,"%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")]
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 419172 items of column 'TimeStamp' (recycled leaving remainder of 6 items).
2: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Coerced 'list' RHS to 'character' to match the column's type. Either change the target column to 'list' first (by creating a new 'list' vector length 419172 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'character' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
> str(dataTs1)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  419172 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ TimeStamp: chr  "c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N"| __truncated__ "c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N"| __truncated__ "c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N"| __truncated__ "c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N"| __truncated__ ...
 $ V6FCDSB  : chr  "ALL1" "ALL1" "ALL1" "ALL1" ...
 $ V6FCDTD  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ _TYPE_   : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ N        : int  621 810 4 4 8 1 3 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: What version of R are you using? There used to be a memory leak with `strptime`.

Comment: You should assign by reference:  `dataTs1[,TimeStamp:=strptime(TimeStamp,"%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")]`

Comment: @James I am using version 3.0.0

Comment: @Roland, Thanks, but I keep getting the same error with both methods

Comment: @RickyBobby I was mistaken, the bug was to `format.POSIXlt` which is called by `strftime`. `strptime` calls separate code. The bug was fixed in 2.11.1, but here it is for reference: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14267

Comment: @RickyBobby The errors in your edits are because `strptime` outputs `POSIXlt` objects. You might want to use `as.POSIXct` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIXlt is not supported by data.table and never will be. ["The no-support for POSIXlt is set in stone"](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.datatable/1585/match=posixlt)